# .Net Custom Libraries?

Tags: asp.net, database

Where can I get custom libraries for ASP .Net? Specifically I am looking for ready made database access library that allow me to select, insert and update a database using transactions. I know how to do create but I am trying to use an existent library that does all that and handles exceptions and errors so exempt from the hustle of creating that from scratch and go into errors.

Comment: Our web guy likes Duke Nukem....err....[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) and its community of themes, plugins, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Microsoft's free [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx) for DataAccess, Logging, Caching, Security and Configuration. It's very commonly used.

Also you can use code generators like free [.NET Tiers](http://nettiers.com/), but you will need [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at either using [LINQtoSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) and the DBML designer to map your database tables onto objects in your system or a more full-featured ORM, like [nHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at something called [Speedy.net](http://www.openbracketllc.com/products/speedy/Data/Default.aspx).  I have never used it, but it looks interesting.  I have used other code that these people have written, and normally it's pretty good.  For the small amount of money that it costs it might be worth trying out.